# Switch addClass per click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got an element that I want to append per click. And every time it has appended I want it to have a certain class.
For example: I click once, it appends with the `class="odd"`, click again there will be an element with the `class="even"`.
So in the end it will look something like

```
class="odd"
class="even"
class="odd"
class="even"
etc.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1360v7gn/

Comment: You may also be interested in the [`:nth-of-type pseudo class`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo), which also is accepting the keywords `even` and `odd` as argument.

Comment: @NicoO Are you suggesting that they scrap the jQuery to determine which class is needed and just use CSS selectors to handle the appropriate colouring instead? (Because if so, that's a really good idea.)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist depending on the actual usecase: yes.

Comment: @NicoO Here's your proposal just for fun: http://jsfiddle.net/1360v7gn/17/

Comment: @technophobia that's a really clever solution, nice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var clicks = 0;

$('li').on('click', function () {
    var element = '<div></div>';
    // per click it should change the addClass
    if (clicks % 2 == 0) { //check for an even number
        $(this).append($(element).addClass('even'));
    } else {
        $(this).append($(element).addClass('odd'));
    }

    clicks++;
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1360v7gn/1/)**

It gets a bit more complex if you need to start with the number of divs inside a particular list item, but not much.

Comment: Wow that was fast. Exactly what I was searching for! Thank you, in 8 minutes i'll check this as the answer

Comment: The "scope" of the click should be per `li` element, otherwise, you can end up messing the alternating order.

Comment: That's what my closing comment referred to, but the OP didn't indicate that it was a concern.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the toggling is per `<li>` element, rather than for each click. Since the starting class may not always be 'odd', you'll want to get the last descendent `<div>` element in the `<li>` that was clicked on, like so:

```
var last = $(this).find('div.odd, div.even').last();
```

---

There's a few ways you could write that line which would all work the same way. You could just use 'div' as the selector (i.e. `$(this).find('div').last()`). You could use `.children()` instead of `.find()` to only look one level down within the `<li>` element.

So if there's a number of variations that end up being equivalent, why did I choose that one? It's the most resilient to potential changes to the DOM structure. If you add another wrapping element between the `<li>` and those `<div>` elements, `.children()` wouldn't work (though you'd also have to go and fix the line that appends the new element). If you have other `<div>` elements that you don't want to count, just using 'div' as the selector also wouldn't work.

---

Then determine which class the new element should have by checking whether it has the 'odd' class - if it does, the new element needs the 'even' class; otherwise, it needs 'odd'.

```
var c = last.hasClass('odd') ? 'even' : 'odd';
$(this).append($(element).addClass(c));
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1360v7gn/16/)

Comment: Your answer is pretty close, but you're `mod` 2 is flawed as it doesn't check the state of the first element.  This could be the best answer if that is fixed.

Comment: @technophobia Good point. I'd sort of expect it to always start with `odd`, but that's not actually the case in the demo. Updated my answer to check which of the classes the last child element has.

Comment: You can also simplify the query for `last` to just be `$(this).find('div').last()`, but the logic is very sound. update: never mind, it looks like you're being safe. Wise.

Comment: @technophobia I had a note about that in my original answer which I deleted. My concern was potentially other `<div>` elements (inside the odd or even divs, possibly) throwing things off. That may not actually be a concern but it doesn't hurt to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

This works in your jsfiddle:

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
    var currentClass = $(this).children().last().attr('class');
    var setClass = (currentClass === "odd") ? "even" : "odd";
    var $div = $('<div class="'+setClass+'"/>');
    $(this).append($div); // per click it should change the addClass
});
```

Comment: This will break if the elements have other classes on them (i.e. the `class` attribute isn't just the string "odd"). May be better to use `.hasClass()` to check for the presence of that class.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this does what you want:

```
$('li').on('click', function () {
    var element = '<div></div>';
    var newClass = ($(this).find('div:last').attr('class')=='odd')?'even':'odd';
    $(this).append($(element).addClass(newClass)); // per click it should change the addClass
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/1360v7gn/15/)**